# How exactly should I use the source command to avoid getting errors

Tags: vim, neovim

So I'm trying to use the source(`:so`) command but I keep getting this error:

`E471: Argument required`

I would appreciate knowing what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:source` can be used in two ways:

```
" sources file foobar.vim
:source foobar.vim

" evaluates each line in [range] as vimscript
:[range]source
```

but the latter is a recent addition.

The fact that you can't use `:source` without an argument suggests that either your version of Vim is outdated or you are using Neovim, which apparently hasn't merged that patch already.

Comment: If you are in the second case, Neovim started its life as a fork of Vim 7.4 9 years ago. A lot happened in the meantime in both projects and it is a mistake to presume that they are interoperable. In concrete terms: when you read about a Vim or Neovim feature somewhere, never assume that you can use it, too.